# Completely LVM installation

Tags: grub2, lvm

Did anyone tried to install Ubuntu completely with LVM, with /boot partition inside LVM?

I've got no luck with installing GRUB to disk, which has no MBR, or has MBR, but no partition.

Comment: I have done full LVM installs. I don't understand how you could possibly have a MBR and no partitions, though. What I did was make one primary parition covering all the disk, format is as an LVM physical disk, and make a LVM volume group on it.

Comment: Please reinstall it...

Comment: @AlexP why do you need MBR to be alongside with LVM? Look, LVM could use the whole disk just fine, not the partition. And doesn't it look strange, to use new shiny method of partition management along with old and stupid MBR?

Comment: LVM can use the whole disk, that's true; on data disks this is perfectly reasonable. But on a boot disk the stage 1 boot loader needs to live somewhere. That somewhere can be either the MBR gap between the MBR and the first partition, of a dedicated EFI system partition. In both cases you have a partition table.

Comment: @AlexP LVM does not start at the beginning of the disk. It usually leaves 1 Mb empty at the beginning. So there is no problem to put bootstrap code there, even if we would like to use GRUB with his stage 1.5.